# How to "Uninstall" your facebook page tab app from a page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps, facebook-page

I have developed a facebook page tab app for my website and now I want to give the user option to uninstall the app from my website.

So far, I have been successful in removing the app from page tabs, but the app is still there and can be brought back via page's "Edit info" link.

The drawback for me is that I can not re post my app to the same page. Is there any way I could uninstall the app instead of removing it?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is described for [`tabs` connection on `page`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#tabs) object documentation (see Delete clause):

Just issue DELETE request to:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/tabs/TAB_ID
```

Or same with GET

```
http://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/tabs/TAB_ID?method=delete
```